Rename "centrifuge" tag to "centrifugo" tag
According to this webpage "centrifuge" changed its name to "centrifugo". Therefore I think that the centrifuge tag should be renamed to centrifugo. I see people are asking questions about "centrifugo" but having to tag the questions with "centrifuge". I also think that changing the tag name will help to correctly complete the tag wiki.

It seems that they still have a library for Go called centrifuge which is what Centrifugo is built on top of. It does seem like none of the questions are about that library though.

Has anyone checked if everything tagged [centrifuge] is about [centrifugo]?

@AbdulAzizBarkat so perhaps a new tag centrifugo and in the tag wiki state that it was formerly centrifuge and in the existing centrifuge tag wiki state that it is for the library written in GO language and that questions regarding centrifugo should use that tag.

@Zoe-Savethedatadump search returns eleven questions. I understand that the name was changed in 2015 so questions posted before then refer to centrifuge but it looks to me that all questions posted after the name change all have to do with centrifugo. Pardon, looks like this question is about the GO library.

@Zoe-Savethedatadump this one is not about centrifugo and I'm not sure about these: 1 and 2, rest everything else should be about centrifugo

@Abra that one is still about centrifugo, they have two Go libraries one is centrifuge which is what centrifugo is built on top of and the other is centrifuge-go which is their SDK to interact with centrifugo.

@AbdulAzizBarkat The one you're unsure about: seems to be about a different thing by the same organisation. [substrate] is not the right tag for not; probably need a brand new tag ([go-substrate] would be the convention, but doesn't feel like a good name). 1: it is indeed about centrifugo, as per the archive of the link in the question (https://web.archive.org/web/20180212164706/https://centrifuge.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) 2: https://github.com/centrifugal/centrifuge-android - not sure if we want a separate tag for it or not. Depends on how different it is

@Zoe-Savethedatadump "by the same organisation" no, its a different organization "centrifuge" vs "centrifugal". I'm not sure about 2 because I can't seem to find anything like Centrifuge.newCredentials in the centrifuge-android package from that org, maybe it's some old code of theirs though.

@AbdulAzizBarkat "no, it's a different organization" - indeed they are, my bad. "maybe it's some old code of theirs though" - I couldn't find the source, but the exact same question was posted as an issue by the same person, so that's a pretty clear answer at least

There are only 11 questions to consider AFAICT, doesn't seem like a big deal.
